# Serial Port Communication with C# application results in Application Hang during Hibernate and resume ( Windows OS)

Tags: c#-4.0, operating-system, serial-port

My C# Application with Serial port Communication features gets hang during hibernate and resume.

OS: Windows

**Problem:**
I have a Two machines( Machine A and Machine B) communicating with each other using serial port and respective cables.

After Establishing the connection, I want my Machine A to go for Hibernate option in windows OS.

During this scenario repeatedly, i observe my Machine A application hangs.

**Debug Data:**

After resume from hibernate & During the Hang state on Machine A, I could see that Object which i have created , does have valid properties , but it does not have any method accessible (Code Debug). I am not getting any exception also for this. 
Example: Code hangs at SerialPortObject.Close() or SerailPortObject.WriteLine()

**Need**
Suggestion for solving this issue.

Comment: If you can't get a USB driver update for your emulator then throw it away and get another one from a different manufacturer.  Spend more money on it.